# Netbeans-ide 8.2 change colors without themes

Tags: netbeans, ide

I am running NetBeans-ide 8.2 on Windows 7 SP1, and I found where to change the colors of the editor OK.

I want to change the colors for the project pane, and the others too, but I don't want to install a "theme".

Using a theme changes all the colors but, while I may be able to find one I like, I want more control.

I assume there is some kind of configuration file that tells NetBeans what colors to use (Like one might use regedit to change things in Windows.)

I see there are a bunch of xml files in various directories under NetBeans. Something there?

Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 3):

> *I want to change the colors for the project pane, and the others too,
>   but I don't want to install a "theme".*

With regard to the **Projects** pane, the only way I know of to change that  (without using a theme) is by changing the look and feel. This is similar to using a theme, except that it is specified in a different way, and does not impact the editor window:

- To specify a theme (which I realize you don't want to do): **Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Profile**
- To specify a look and feel: **Tools-> Options -> Appearance -> Look and Feel -> Preferred look and feel**

Note that the look and feel options come bundled with NetBeans, but your choices are fairly limited. Also, there is no preview functionality; you have to restart NetBeans to see if you like the new look and feel.

> *I want more control*

Since you don't want to use a theme your options are fairly limited unfortunately, but you can set the font colors and background color for the **Output** Window and/or the **Terminal** Window. To do that:

- Select **Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous**
- Select the **Output** tab and/or the **Terminal** tab where you can play with various color settings.

Both tabs give you a preview, and the changes are immediately effective. See the screen shot below with:

- The default **NetBeans** profile (i.e. theme) with **Nimbus** look and feel.
- All the tabs in the **Output** window have a cyan background.
- The **Terminal** window has a yellow background.

[image]

> *I assume there is some kind of configuration file that tells NetBeans
>   what colors to use*

If only! I expect there are multiple configuration files, and I suspect that if you played around with them you could do more with color customization, but as far as I know those configuration files are not publicly documented. I've just described what is supported through the GUI of NetBeans.